# How to change windows key bindings to look like mac osX?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

Im very used to mac, I use it at work, and when I get home I aways get lost with the keys shortcuts on windows... 
is there some way to remap those shortcuts in windows 7? To feel like in macos?

Answer (score 2):

I use autohotkey to remap keys on my keyboard. Find more information about autohotkeys [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of programs for windows that will remap keys for you, like [sharpkeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/). So if you wanted to rebind ctl to act like another key, you could. Based on key position you might want to rebind ctl to windows button, etc. so you hit the right keys when you're going for shortcuts. In the general windows interface, most key shortcut combos (like ctl + c to copy, etc.) will be set but again you can change what key corresponds to ctl if it makes you feel more comfortable. 
As for within individual programs (e.g. word), you can usually go to Options or Preferences and change shortcuts so they are done the same way as in Mac.